# Question related to the photo in contactsi of my iPone 4

Tags: iphone

To whom or where can I send a suggestion to improve the iOS OS for the iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of contact/feedback option on [Apple - How to Contact Us](http://www.apple.com/contact/) and a separate page for [Product Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/). Take your pick.